# pseduo-backround image::after in CSS for full HTML body does not repeat when scrolling down

Tags: css

my question is in the title. I know this might be very stupid but I would be super grateful for any help. I have this CSS:

```css
body::after {
  background: url("../img/IMAGE.jpg");
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

The image only repeats in screen-size and does not display if I scroll down the HTML page. What can I do? many thanks!

Comment: You might want to use `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`. Absolute positioning will scroll along with the content, fixed positioning will stay. Or you could also try setting the `height` of `::after` to `100%` instead of setting a `bottom` value so it would resize along with the height of the body regardless of the amount of content it has.

Comment: thanks ! So far the only thing that works is position: fixed. That makes the image fixed and the text scrolls in front of it. This is not really I wanted but fine for now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using bottom: -100% (or the percentage needed but negative, e.g. -200%, etc) and height: auto:

```
body::after {
   bottom: -100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: thanks! This only makes the image two times the screen size when I scroll down but does not continue after. How can I make the bottom "endless"? bottom: auto and bottom: inherit do not work

Comment: OK now I just added bottom:  -100000%; and it works , many thanks!!! ALthough now it is too big but I can adjust. thanks